# mysqldump error #1557: corrupt event table?

Tags: mysql

I just noticed the following error from my old mysql backup scripts:

```
% mysqldump -hsql -uXXXX -pXXXX --events --all-databases > /dev/null 
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show events': Cannot proceed because system tables
     used by Event Scheduler were found damaged at server start (1577)
```

Poking around seems to indicate some sort of corruption with mysql.events (I can dump without errors if I skip the --events flag). I'm worried that something's seriously wrong with the database and can't fine any clear instance of someone reporting the same problem. Closest match seems to indicate that myisamchk should be used to rebuild the ISA index, but I'm not convinced it's the same problem.

I'm running mysql v14.14 on an ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS system. Other than this error, I'm not seeing any other symptoms/problems.

I was hoping someone could provide some advice before I start poking around and risk really corrupting the db.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sounds like a broken mysql upgrade.

I would suggest to try :

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -h localhost -p --verbose --force
```

and then `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Finally, try again :)