# Missing File: /etc/init.d/mysql or /etc/init.d/mysqld does not exist

Tags: mysql, web-server, mariadb

We are running mySQL on a Fedora Linux fc19.

I have a few corrupt event table errors like in this ticket:
[mysqldump error #1557: corrupt event table?](https://serverfault.com/questions/562282/mysqldump-error-1557-corrupt-event-table/562303#562303)

However, when I to to run step two, "/etc/init.d/mysql restart", restarting mysql bash returns the following:
"/etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory"

phpMyAdmin and the websites appear to be running normally, which makes me believe that the "/etc/init.d/mysql" file is somewhere on the box. Is there some sort of search I can do to locate it? Would the pages still operate if it is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 19 (which is **way** out of support - time to upgrade) is based on systemd and something along the line of `systemctl restart mysqld.service` should work (or `service mysqld restart` if you use the old style interface).

Comment: Haha, I actually had a comment "Yeah, I know that this is way out of date" but decided to remove it. The later worked, thanks!